# Typescript Interface extension / Generic

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typescript-generics

lets assume we have a typescript frontend that relies on mongoose queries. The interface of a example document looks something like this

```
export interface Item {
    name: string;
    sku: string;
    manufacturer: Manufacturer;
    foo: bar;
    ...
}
```

This works great for creating documents, but as soon as data is fetched from the database, there's additional data attached, like "_id", "_createdAt" etc. In the past, I went for a pretty cumbersome approach of creating an interface like "MongooseDocumentItem" and extended the original one with the additional data. But as soon as you do that, you repeat yourself when creating the next interface. So in reality, something like

```
export interface MongooseDocument<T> {
    _id: string;
    data: T;
    ...
}
```

is needed. But this approach changes the interface from the incoming data structure (pushed into a data key). What is the correct way to this? There should be a pretty obvious solution which i have missed.

Comment: Consider using [typegoose](https://typegoose.github.io/typegoose/) or [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) if you're using TypeScript with mongodb.

Answer (score 0):

The common approach would be to use the `Document` type supplied by mongoose and extend it.

```
import { Document } from "mongoose"

export interface Item {
    name: string;
    sku: string;
}

export interface ItemDocument extends Document, Item {}
```

```
declare const item: ItemDocument

item._id
```

But this does not include the `createdAt` or `updatedAt` fields. So you might want to create your own `TimestampDocument` to extend from.

```
interface TimestampDocument extends Document {
    createdAt: Date
    updatedAt: Date
}

export interface ItemDocument extends TimestampDocument, Item {}
```

```
declare const item: ItemDocument

item.name
item.sku

item._id
item.updatedAt
item.createdAt
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgEQgYwK4gKYDt4C+cAZlBCHAEQgS4DmEEAztpQFBvYAekscw+bFGIBDNNjgBJGNgoI2cRXFwicALjhMYUAXQDcCpUwDWGDVp30DBDgJnCxEgCqhsW1WFSYc+ONxm4ACZMKOhYePDySnBoUNgiMoEAgjAayAnYhooYYIEZyakoGWw2nDzQ8HZCouJSMiBe4b7+eMFwLjju4I0+MAA0dbKIpYHYaAA2InExtFr89RrSsj0RtvUAdCo4bMAbJhhrsusA+sCBOxs5eYkpF0ex8TcwQA)